# HTML <audio> tag's canplaythrough not firing on mobile

Tags: javascript, ios, audio

I'm playing with HTML 5 `<audio>` tags. I found it very cool, but just encountered a very weird situation. In short, the `canplaythrough` doesn't fire on mobile as expected.

In this case, I have a few buttons on a webpage:

```
<button id="sndbtn01" onclick="createAudioById('01')">Audio 01</button>
<button id="sndbtn02" onclick="createAudioById('02')">Audio 02</button>
<button id="sndbtn03" onclick="createAudioById('03')">Audio 03</button>
<button id="sndbtn04" onclick="createAudioById('04')">Audio 04</button>
```

What I expect is to play 01.mp3 when "Audio 01" is clicked, and the similar action for clicking "Audio 02", "Audio 03", "Audio 04" buttons. And I hope the `<audio>` tag is created when the button clicked, so that I can save traffic without preloading everything.

So, I have the JavaScript code:

```
  var audioObj = {};
  function createAudioById(id){
    var p = audioObj[id];
    // alert(1)
    if (p != undefined) {
      alert(2);
      p.play();
      return;
    } else {
      alert(3);
      p = new Audio();
      p.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function(e){
        e.currentTarget.removeEventListener('canplaythrough', arguments.callee);
        alert(4);
        p.play();
      });
      p.src = '../snds/'+id+'.mp3';
      audioObj[id] = p;
    }
  }
```

But the behavior is weird on mobile devices:

On Mobile (iPhone):

1. First click on `button 01` triggers the `(3)`, and then nothing happens - the `canplaythrough` event is never fired and the audio never got played  - NOT as expected: the `(4)` should fire and audio should get played;
2. If I click again on the button, the `(2)` would trigger and the audio is played. But what's weird is that the `(4)` is fired a few seconds later after the audio starts to play.
3. If I click on the button while the audio is playing, the `(2)` is triggered and nothing happens, the audio keeps playing - as expected;
4. If I click on the button while the audio is done playing, the `(2)` will triggered, audio played and `(4)` never pop up - as expected.

Answer (score 0):

On Desktop:

I don't see why this is strange behavior. You first check if the audio with the name '01' exists. It doesn't, so you create it, and when it's finished loading and can play through, the event listener is fired and it starts playing.

Then, you press the button again while it's playing. You check if the audio with the name '01' exists - it does, because you previously created it and it's still playing. Therefore, p is defined and the (2) triggers. The audio keeps playing because you told it to play, which it was already doing.

Then, when the audio is stopped and you press the button, you check if the audio with the name '01' exists. It still exists - it stopped playing, but it still exists, it's just paused now that the song is over. So the (2) triggers and you tell it to play, but the event listener is still listening, you never destroyed it, so when it redownloads the song, canplaythrough gets triggered a second time. This is all normal behavior.

On mobile:
You have the exact same setup, except this time around for whatever reason the canplaythrough event isn't triggering. I don't know why that is, but that's a whole other question. The behavior, other than that, is easily explained. You create new audio, for some reason the event isn't triggered, so when you click the button again the audio still exists from when you created it before and it starts playing. Then, when the song is finished, the audio still exists and still has the event listener on it, but once again, for some reason that event listener doesn't work at all, but the audio gets played anyway because it still exists.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried again and found that `canplaythrough` does trigger everytime I invoke audioelement.play(); - this is a bit weird. Anyway, how do I remove the event listener in this case?

And do you have any clues about why the event is not fired on mobile?

Comment: I don't know why canplaythrough isn't bring triggered on mobile, but to remove the event listener just add e.currentTarget.removeEventListener('canplaythrough') inside the function that the event listener triggers to get rid of the event listener when it is triggered the first time. Make sure you add the parameter e to the function opening like function handler(e) {

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question but after adding the `e.currentTarget.removeEventListener('canplaythrough')` the `(4)` is still firing - you can see the edited question for my latest code.

Comment: In order for e.currentTarget.removeEventListener to work the function needs to have a name, it can't be anonymous. Use function handler(e) {

Comment: I forgot to pass in the reference. And I just solve it by using `e.currentTarget.removeEventListener('canplaythrough', arguments.callee);` Thanks!